# Cloud run triggered by file upload in bucket by pub sub push notification runs multiple times

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

I have a Cloud Run service(Express Endpoint) that is triggered by a Pub/Sub push notification when a file is uploaded to a Cloud Storage bucket. However, the Cloud Run service is getting triggered multiple times for each file upload, which is causing duplicate processing. I have set the acknowledgment deadline to 10 minutes, but it does not help.

Here's how the code looks like(ignoring functions implementations):

```
app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    
    try {
        console.log("Post endpoint is hited")
        const file = decodeBase64Json(req.body.message.data);
        const csvData = await downloadFile(storage, file.bucket, file.name);
        await removeHydrofoilsConfigurations();
        console.log("Procesiong of csv started")
        await processData(csvData);
        res.status(200).send("Cloud run finished csv processing successfully");
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(`Error: ${ex}`);
        res.status(400).send("Cloud run failed during csv processing");
    }
    
});
```

The downloadFile function is this:

```
async function downloadFile(storage, bucketName, fileName) {
    const options = { destination: `/tmp/${fileName}` };
    await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).download(options);
    const filePath = `/tmp/${fileName}`;
    const csvData = [];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.createReadStream(filePath)
            .pipe(csv())
            .on("data", (data) => csvData.push(data))
            .on("end", () => {
                try {
                    if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
                        fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
                        console.log("File deleted successfully");
                    } else {
                        console.log("File does not exist");
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                }
                resolve(csvData);
            })
            .on("error", (error) => reject(error));
    });
}
```

Comment: Which Cloud Storage events are you triggering upon?

Comment: @JohnHanley I am triggering upon upload of file in a bucket.

Comment: There are multiple events. Which ones are you triggering on - the actual event names?

Comment: @JohnHanley OBJECT_FINALIZE is the event name.

Comment: Edit your question and show each event (with details) that you are receiving that shows duplicate OBJECT_FINALIZE. The better the details, the easier to analyze. Also, review the logs to see if events are being retried.

Comment: @JohnHanley Where to find logs? I am running express middleware in the cloud run. When the file is uploaded, I logged the request.body in the code. It does not give any event-related info.

Comment: 1) post the results from your code. 2) Cloud Run logs are located in a Cloud Run GUI tab and in Cloud Logging.

Comment: @JohnHanley I used Evenarc instead of pub/sub and there is no duplication now, even though eventarc is built on top of pub/sub.